# firebase function location date found country time how to observe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

firebase function I want to print a child's time zone of the country I am in, but it is showing
the server time can you help me with this ?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var database = admin.database();
var tarih = new Date();

exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('Kullanicilar/{userId}/sistemdurumu')
.onWrite((Change, Context) =>{
    var oldDeger = Change.before.val();
    var newDeger = Change.after.val();
    
    

    if (newDeger > oldDeger){
     database.ref(`Kullanicilar/${Context.params.userId}/sistemdurumu1`).set(tarih.getFullYear());
     database.ref(`Kullanicilar/${Context.params.userId}/sistemdurumu2`).set(tarih.getMonth()+1);
     database.ref(`Kullanicilar/${Context.params.userId}/sistemdurumu3`).set(tarih.getDate()); 
     database.ref(`Kullanicilar/${Context.params.userId}/sistemdurumu4`).set(tarih.getHours());  
    // database.ref(`system/${Context.params.userId}/otherField`).update({another:field});
    }
   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to store user's timezone in database to calculate the time in their region manually.

```
const tarih = Date.now() // Current Timestamp

const userTimeZoneOffset = 9 // GMT+9 Tokyo

const timeInRegion = new Date(d + (userTimeZoneOffset*60*60*1000)).toISOString()

console.log(timeInRegion)
```

There are some libraries such as [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) to change time formats. I haven't used it but that may be useful if you don't want to do the timezone calculations manually.

Comment: Thanks for your help it worked. can I ask one more question

Comment: @ufuksipor sure if it's related to this one. If it's different then it's  recommend to ask different question :D

Comment: I wrote this question as an answer to the question I asked you to make it more readable. I would be very grateful if you could help me with this question.

Comment: @ufuksipor read my comment on that answer. Also add `await` before every set statement.

Comment: database.ref(`Kullanicilar/${Context.params.userId}/sistemdurumu1`).await().set(timeInRegion.getFullYear());  
there was no change